# CodeIgniter 4 will not recognize UserModel

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am using CodeIgniter 4 on Windows 10 and I'm having an issue where CI is not recognizing my model.

I am receiving the following error upon form submission:

> Error 
> Class 'CodeIgniter\Models\UserModel' not found 
> APPPATH\Controllers\User.php at line 42

CI is displaying this line (in User.php) as the source of the issue:

> $model = new UserModel();

Here is my User controller file (app/Controllers/User.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use CodeIgniter\Models\UserModel;

class User extends Controller {
    public function index() {
      return redirect()->to('/user/signin');
    }

    public function signin() {
      $data = [];
      helper(['form']);

      echo view('templates/dashkit/head');
      echo view('templates/dashkit/signin', $data);
      echo view('templates/dashkit/foot');

      return;
    }

    public function register() {
      $data = [];
      helper(['form']);

      if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {
        $rules = [
          'company' => 'required|min_length[8]|is_unique[users.user_company]',
          'email' => 'required|min_length[11]|max_length[255]|valid_email|is_unique[users.user_email]',
          'firstname' => 'required|min_length[2]|max_length[50]',
          'lastname' => 'required|min_length[2]|max_length[50]',
          'password' => 'min_length[8]|max_length[255]',
          'password_confirm' => 'matches[password]',
        ];

        if(!$this->validate($rules)) {
          $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
        } else {
          // If the information passes validation, add the user to the database
          $model = new UserModel();

          $newData = [
            'company'   => $this->request->getVar('company'),
            'email'     => $this->request->getVar('email'),
            'firstname' => $this->request->getVar('firstname'),
            'lastname'  => $this->request->getVar('lastname'),
            'password'  => $this->request->getVar('password')
          ];
          $model->save($newData);
          $session = session();
          $session->setFlashdata('success', 'The form was successfully submitted.');
          return redirect()->to('/dashboard');
        }
      }

      echo view('templates/dashkit/head');
      echo view('templates/dashkit/register', $data);
      echo view('templates/dashkit/foot');

      return;
    }
}
```

And here is my UserModel file (app/Models/UserModel.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model {
  protected $allowedFields = ['user_company', 'user_created_at', 'user_email', 'user_firstname', 'user_lastname', 'user_password'];
  protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
  protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];
  protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
  protected $table = 'users';

  protected function beforeInsert(array $data) {
    if(isset($data['data']['password'])) {
      $data['data']['password'] = password_hash($data['data']['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }

    return $data;
  }

  protected function beforeUpdate(array $data) {


    return $data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert in codeIgniter, but looks like your namespace is actually `App\Models` ..
So try `use App\Models\UserModel;` ?

Comment: I actually tried that already. I get a "CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DataException There is no data to insert." error. However, double and triple-checking the CI 4 documentation confirms that the namespace should be "use CodeIgniter\Models\UserModel;"

Comment: In that case, are you supposed to extend the Model like `extends CI_Model` ?

Comment: I've tried that as well and saw no change in errors. From what I've gathered from other Stack Overflow questions, that is only for CodeIgniter 3.

Comment: Hmm, I see.. Even the documentation has what you've got.. I'm out of ideas.. Hopefully someone with better CI knowledge can help

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's much appreciated!

Comment: 1st comment of @Pogrindis is correct: [check](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html#display-the-news). Now you have to work on your database setup errors

Comment: @Vickel, hmm. On other documentation pages it does say to use CodeIgniter\ there. Weird, thanks for that! Any ideas then why I'm now receiving a "There is no data to insert." error message? I added a ```print_r($newData);``` statement above ```$model->save($newData);``` which confirms that the data is not empty..

Comment: most likely because no primary key was set: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=save (browse to save() section

Comment: @Vickel, you're right! After adding a primary key to the query it now inserts properly into my database. Thanks!

Comment: I've made my comments an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to follow the namespace rules as in the [documents](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html#display-the-news):

```
namespace App\Controllers;   

use App\Models\NewsModel;    // App instead of CodeIgniter
use CodeIgniter\Controller;
```

Second, the error you receive consequently (as mentioned in your comment):

> CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DataException "There is no data to
> insert."

is caused because there is no primary key set for `$model->save($newData);`

see [Saving Data](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?#saving-data):

> save(): This is a wrapper around the insert() and update() methods
> that handle inserting or updating the record automatically, based on
> whether it finds an array key matching the $primaryKey value